# Plot column from dataframe with dates in x axis

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a dataframe with multiple attributes. I have a column amount and a column date which is of format (dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm/ss) or (dd/mm/yyyy).
I would like to have the amount on axis y and the date on axis x.

My code here does not raise any errors but the plot is not what I am looking for as it seems that the date is not handled :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as pplt 
    newAcc['EuroAmount']=newAcc['EuroAmount'].apply(pd.to_numeric)
    newAcc['EuroAmount'].plot(x='AccountingDataCreation')
    pplt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html):

```
newAcc.set_index('AccountingDataCreation')['EuroAmount'].plot()
```

Or [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
newAcc.plot(x='AccountingDataCreation', y='EuroAmount')
```

Comment: It is weird, it is working I think but my AccountingDataCreation is ordered and my x axis is not ordered, I have 08/02 then 07/02 then 08/02 again

Comment: Try convert to datetime by `newAcc['AccountingDataCreation'] = pd.to_datetime(newAcc['AccountingDataCreation'])` first

Comment: ok i'll try, I also found I had a date in another format that might be confusing the algorithm i am changing that

Comment: I see you have first days, so `newAcc['AccountingDataCreation'] = pd.to_datetime(newAcc['AccountingDataCreation'], dayfirst=True)` ?

Comment: I finally finished formatting my string to the same format, I tried to apply the `to_datetime()` and i got a `Keyerror :AccountingDataCreation`. Is it because i am tryng to setindex() with a date ?

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure but what is `newAcc.info()` before `set_index` ? Because set _index mean create index from column `AccountingDataCreation`  and then `Series.plot` creates `axis-x` from `index` values.

Comment: OK found it, it was a problem with my csv parser, thank you it is working